# How can I use H2O DAI in static ip?

Tags: proxy, h2o, driverless-ai

I am using a static IP and are now accessing the server with Putty. So I try to use h2o-dai with putty, but it does not work with xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:12345.

I used tar_sh.sh when installing.

So, when I set up ./dai_env.sh, I see no_proxy is localhost, 127.0.0.1 and NO_PROXY is

What is this and why is not it?

and **How do I resolve it?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you verify that DAI is running? you can check your logs to see if dai is running.

Comment: Try adding an ssh tunnel to your putty configuration for that connection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand the comments well.
Then I found a page. https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.h2o.ai/releases/ai/h2o/dai/rel-1.2.2-6/docs/userguide/setting-environment-variables.html#configtoml
It is this page.
There is a part where I edit ip.
I put the static ip here, but it did not.
Is it correct to edit this part?

Comment: That said, log file is http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/linux-tarsh.html#looking-at-driverless-ai-log-files This page Are you saying you want to try it again? Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead) I hear these words.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the firewall on your system using tcping from another linux server or your windows to server which you installed h2o dai.

ex) tcping -t host-ip port (linux to linux)

If you get a response like bellows, have to open a specific port which your solution use.

[root@localhost /]# tcping -t 5 your-ip port

your-ip port port# closed.